# How can I get current frame in vlc-qt?

Tags: qt, vlc-qt

I make an app that stream video from IP camera by using vlc-qt with Qt 5.7, and I want to get current frame for processing. How I can do it with VlcVideoStream class. 
Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check this: https://github.com/vlc-qt/vlc-qt/issues/66. The Auther added a API named VlcVideoStream for get stream data.

Comment: Have someone tried to use subclass VlcVideoStream and use it? I used it and only get a black screen. Someone know how it works?